# Processing files in a particular order in R

Tags: r, filenames

I have several datafiles, which I need to process in a particular order. The pattern of the names of the files is, e.g. `"Ad_10170_75_79.txt"`.

Currently they are sorted according to the first numbers (which differ in length), see below:

```
f <- as.matrix (list.files())
f
[1] "Ad_10170_75_79.txt" "Ad_10345_76_79.txt" "Ad_1049_25_79.txt"  "Ad_10531_77_79.txt"
```

But I need them to be sorted by the middle number, like this:

```
> f
[1] "Ad_1049_25_79.txt" "Ad_10170_75_79.txt" "Ad_10345_76_79.txt"   "Ad_10531_77_79.txt"
```

As I just need the middle number of the filename, I thought the easiest way is, to get rid of the rest of the name and renaming all files. For this I tried using `strsplit` (`plyr`).

```
f2 <- strsplit (f,"_79.txt")
```

But I'm sure there is a way to sort the files directly, without renaming all files. I tried using `sort` and to describe the name with `regex` but without success. This has been a problem for many days, and I spent several hours searching and trying, to solve this presumably easy task. Any help is very much appreciated.

old example dataset:

```
f <- c("Ad_10170_75_79.txt", "Ad_10345_76_79.txt",
       "Ad_1049_25_79.txt", "Ad_10531_77_79.txt")
```

Thank your for your answers. I think I have to modify my example, because the solution should work for all possible middle numbers, independent of their digits.

new example dataset:

```
f <- c("Ad_10170_75_79.txt", "Ad_10345_76_79.txt",
       "Ad_1049_9_79.txt", "Ad_10531_77_79.txt")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a regex approach.

```
f[order(as.numeric(gsub('Ad_\\d+_(\\d+)_\\d+\\.txt', '\\1', f)))]
# [1] "Ad_1049_9_79.txt"   "Ad_10170_75_79.txt" "Ad_10345_76_79.txt" "Ad_10531_77_79.txt"
```

Comment: @May6 updated. You can fix this by wrapping the call the `gsub` with `as.numeric`.

Comment: Thanks this works! Do you know a regex tutorial for dummies? I couldn't find one which is detailed enought for me.

Comment: If R is your language of choice, I recommend `?regex`.

Comment: I have read the `?regex`helppage, but I was looking for a more detailed one. 
This approach works for the small example dataset perfectly fine, unfortunately not for my big one. I think there are several more combinations of numbers in it. For now, I will try to understand how `regex` works and how I can adapt it to my task.

Comment: My mistake - it works for perfectly fine for my big dataset - thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
f[order(as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(f, "_"), "[[", 3))))]
[1] "Ad_1049_25_79.txt"  "Ad_10170_75_79.txt" "Ad_10345_76_79.txt" "Ad_10531_77_79.txt"
```

First we split by `_`, then select the third element of every list element, find the order and subset `f` based on that order.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I have edited my question, because the code just works, if the numbers in the middle have the same length. It doesn't work properly with the new example, the order would be: 75,76,77,9. Sorry, I hadn't thought about this before.

Comment: @May6 this approach should work if your character string is `AD_number_number_number.txt`. It will pick out the third word after a split on `_`.

Comment: My character string is as you said. This solution works, if you add `as.numeric` to the code: f[order(as.numeric(unlist(lapply(strsplit(f, "_"), "[[", 3))))]

Comment: I have edited the answer as suggested, now it will work properly for every number.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a small dataframe containing filenames and their respective extracted indices:

```
f<- c("Ad_10170_75_79.txt","Ad_10345_76_79.txt","Ad_1049_25_79.txt","Ad_10531_77_79.txt")
f2 <- strsplit (f,"_79.txt")
mydb <- as.data.frame(cbind(f,substr(f2,start=nchar(f2)-1,nchar(f2))))
names(mydb) <- c("filename","index")
library(plyr)
arrange(mydb,index)
```

Take the first column of this as your filename vector.

ADDENDUM:

If a numeric index is required, simply convert character to numeric:

```
mydb$index <- as.numeric(mydb$index)
```

Comment: Thank's for your effort. Your solution works for the first example, but not for the second example dataset. It doesn't recognize the numbers as numeric, and therefore the sorting is wrong. I tried solving this problem, but without success. As I need indexing in a later step anyway I would be interested very much in a proper working solution.

Comment: @May6 That is easily achieved, please see the addendum.